# update animation based on time in javascript(independent of frames)

Tags: javascript, canvas, time, game-loop

I am implementing a simple animation using javascript in canvas.An image updates its position based on the time elapsed`dt` between each frame. Here is the code

```
var lastTime=0;
var speed=100;

mySprite = function() {
  this.pos=[0,0];
}

function spritePosition(dt) {
  for (i=0; i < Stuff.sprite.length;i++) {
    Stuff.sprite[i].pos[0] += speed*dt;  
    }
}

function animate(){

  var canvas=document.getElementById('mycan');
  var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

  var now = Date.now();
  var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;

  //clear
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  //update
  spritePosition(dt);
  updateSprite();

  //render
  background(canvas,context);
  draw(context);

  lastTime = now;

  //request new Frame
  requestAnimFrame(function() {
    animate();
  });
}

window.onload=function(){
  init();
  animate();
}
```

### dt

values are in the range 0.3-0.5
But the line

```
Stuff.sprite[i].pos[0] += speed*dt;##
```

assigns position values as 136849325664.90016.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `lastTime` to `0` - so the initial delta is veeeeery long (as of today almost 45 years!). You should make sure to catch the very first run (compare to 0? or initialize `lastTime` with `Date.now()`) and treat it separately, possibly setting `dt` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Added this `if (lastTime == 0) lastTime = Date.now();`to the main loop and it's smooth.